# str_replace_all mistakingly assigning values

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am trying to replace values from the column "day" from the following df.

```
structure(list(Segment = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Position = c(1550L, 
1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 
1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 
1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 1550L, 
1550L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 2327L, 2327L, 2327L, 2327L, 2327L, 
2327L, 2327L, 2327L, 2327L, 2327L, 2327L, 2327L, 2327L, 2327L
), Quail = c(52L, 53L, 54L, 12L, 36L, 48L, 59L, 11L, 12L, 36L, 
48L, 59L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 11L, 12L, 48L, 59L, 59L, 
11L, 36L, 59L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 36L, 59L, 36L, 48L, 
59L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 36L, 48L, 59L, 36L, 59L, 36L, 
48L, 59L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 36L, 48L, 59L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 36L, 48L, 59L, 36L, 59L), Freq = c(0.443883, 0.440835, 0.477273, 
0.761589, 0.186821, 0.072325, 0.748305, 0.986968, 0.99361, 0.664921, 
0.188847, 0.858921, 0.960804, 0.102041, 0.323194, 0.2, 0.449976, 
0.630868, 0.958506, 0.743932, 0.257758, 0.886377, 0.038241, 0.992894, 
0.633987, 0.564021, 0.054054, 0.068994, 0.200188, 0.091693, 0.256094, 
0.165732, 0.988798, 0.46675, 0.997898, 0.954168, 0.993462, 0.996931, 
0.932008, 0.998634, 0.957213, 0.858198, 0.22418, 0.910005, 0.045072, 
0.731313, 0.995946, 0.877519, 0.998066, 0.999401, 0.953812, 0.02749, 
0.043711, 0.065646, 0.032982, 0.025522, 0.023756, 0.02199, 0.020975, 
0.021915, 0.026906, 0.029056, 0.025562, 0.031411, 0.021782, 0.024584, 
0.033382, 0.026406), Group = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("var", 
"varL", "varLQ", "varQ"), class = "factor"), Expo = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("DC", "DI"), class = "factor"), day = c("3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
"7", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "1", "8", "8", "8", "1", 
"1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "1", "1", "8", "8", "8", "1", "1", 
"1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "7", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, -68L), class = "data.frame")
```

For that I produced the following list:

```
p = c("1" = "3",
      "3" = "5",
      "5" = "7",
      "7" = "9",
      "8" = "10")
```

And try to replace using the following:

```
library(stringr)
# Substitute        
VariantsGenomeQuails.sub <- 
  VariantsGenomeQuails %>% 
  mutate(day = case_when(Expo == "DC" ~ str_replace_all(day, p),
                         TRUE ~ as.character(day)))
```

On doing so, I only get 9s and 10s as replacements and missing other values.

If I try replacing the numeric values with letters instead of numbers it works as expected.

I have used this approach many times in the past and never had a problem.

Could you please check what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following two cases. In test case 1, numbers when Expo is "DC" become letters a to e, while in test case 2, all results when Expo is "DC" become "e". This means that, when the newly replaced character has another match available in the list you provided, this code will keep replacing the character until the last one available. So in your original, all results becomes "9" and "10", and in my test case 2, all results are "e". I believe the root cause is `str_replace_all` is vectorize. When you repeatedly apply the `str_replace_all` in `case_when`, it always replace the entire column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Test case 1  
p2 = c("1" = "a",
      "3" = "b",
      "5" = "c",
      "7" = "d",
      "8" = "e")

VariantsGenomeQuails.sub2 <- 
  VariantsGenomeQuails %>% 
  mutate(day = case_when(Expo == "DC" ~ str_replace_all(day, p2),
                         TRUE ~ as.character(day)))

# Test case 2    
p3 = c("1" = "a",
       "a" = "3",
       "3" = "b",
       "b" = "5",
       "5" = "c",
       "c" = "7",
       "7" = "d",
       "d" = "8",
       "8" = "e")

VariantsGenomeQuails.sub3 <- 
  VariantsGenomeQuails %>% 
  mutate(day = case_when(Expo == "DC" ~ str_replace_all(day, p3),
                         TRUE ~ as.character(day)))
```

Here is a fix to your code. Let's not use `str_replace_all`, jsut use match. It works well.

```
VariantsGenomeQuails.sub4 <- 
  VariantsGenomeQuails %>% 
  mutate(day = case_when(
    Expo %in% "DC" & day %in% "1"     ~"3",
    Expo %in% "DC" & day %in% "3"     ~"5",
    Expo %in% "DC" & day %in% "5"     ~"7",
    Expo %in% "DC" & day %in% "7"     ~"9",
    Expo %in% "DC" & day %in% "8"     ~"10",
    TRUE ~ day
  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround would be this, based on the observation that the steps between the 'old' numbers and the replacement numbers is always `2`:

```
df$day[df$Expo=="DC"] <- as.numeric(df$day[df$Expo=="DC"])+2
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much for your comment. May question is actually more on the side of my education than tackling the problem itself. There is something that I fail to see that someone with more experience in R may point right away.

Comment: I've spent a good hour or so but couldn't figure out where the issue arises from. Sorry, mate!

Comment: If that's any help, use `df %>% 
  mutate(day = if_else(Expo == "DC", as.numeric(day) + 2, as.numeric(day)))`